# Remove Space Between Text and Variables

Tags: string, spacing

This is what I have so far - but I can't get rid of the spaces before the exclamation and period. What am I missing?

```
user_name = input("What is your name? ")
user_age = int(input("How old are you? "))

year_born = 2021 - user_age

print("Hello", user_name, "!", "You were born in", year_born, ".")
```

My output - Hello Amanda ! You were born in 2005 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "+" operator for concat Strings in Python without adding spaces. Note only that it is not possible to do `string`  + `int` this case, then we need to make a cast (conversion) to occur as expected.

There are also other ways to concatenate Strings in Python easier than I remember.

Your code would be simplistic:

```
user_name = input("What is your name? ")
user_age = int(input("How old are you? "))

year_born = str(2021 - user_age)

print("Hello", user_name + "!", "You were born in", year_born + ".")
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!